# Java regex only finding one match

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the following regex:

```
(?<=<((Pswrd>)|([^/]{1,2147483646}?:Pswrd>)))((?s).+?)(?=</(\\1))
```

And I have the following text to match:

```
<abc:Pswrd>PASSWORD_ONE</abc:Pswrd>
<Pswrd>PASSWORD_TWO</Pswrd>
```

I need to match the context of both XML tags but is only working for the second one.

The output is:

```
PASSWORD_TWO
```

And it should be:

```
PASSWORD_ONE
PASSWORD_TWO
```

It seems the OR is not working for some reason?

```
 String message = "    <abc:Pswrd>PASSWORD_ONE</abc:Pswrd>\n" +
            "    <Pswrd>PASSWORD_TWO</Pswrd>";

String regex = "(?<=<((Pswrd>)|([^/]{1,2147483646}?:Pswrd>)))((?s).+?)(?=</(\\1))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String group = matcher.group();
    System.out.println(group);
}
```

Thanks

Update: It needs to be the matching group 0.

Comment: Ideally you should use an XML-aware parser to access the tag's content.

Comment: Can the password itself contain `<` or `>` ? https://regex101.com/r/VLghTu/1 If not, the value is in the second capturing group.

Comment: If you have good reasons not to, assuming your tag never contains child tags, I would use the following regex : `<(?:[^:>]+:)?Pswrd>([^<]*)</(?:[^:>]+:)?Pswrd>` (tested [here](https://ideone.com/fy1L96))

Comment: @Thefourthbird - It should only match the content.

Comment: The value is in capturing group 2. In Java you have to double escape the backslash

Comment: See my updated comment, I had used an incorrect syntax for non-capturing groups in the first comment. And the result is in the capturing group 1 indeed (now that my non-capturing group have been fixed). The ideone test now works too

Comment: @Thefourthbird - Is possible somehow to put it in the capturing group 0?

Comment: @Aaron Is possible to be in capturing group 0? Only noticed now that I can't change the code where the matching is done.

Comment: Capturing groups start at index 1, but most tools consider group 0 as a shortcut to the whole match, which I assume is what you mean. It's possible using lookarounds as you did. I'd use `(?<=Pswrd>)[^<]+(?=</(?:[^:>]+:)?Pswrd>)` then

Comment: Yes @Aaron that was what I mean. Your regex is only finding the PASSWORD_ONE.

Comment: Yeah, I had a few mistakes in my regex once again, I should really test them before answering. `(?<=[<:]Pswrd>)[^<]+(?=</(?:[^:>]+:)?Pswrd>)`, tested [here](https://ideone.com/Ub3S4r)

Comment: @Aaron It's working perfectly. Thanks allot

Answer (score 0):

So in order to either match `<Pswd>` or `<abc:Pswd>` or `<something:Pswd>`, the RegEx would need to look something like `<\w*:*Pswrd>`. The problem however is that the look behind does not like non-fixed width quantifiers, so you can't create a look behind that caters for a "dynamic"

Instead I would suggest just go for something simple, such as :

```
(?<=Pswrd>)(.*)(?=<\/)
```

Essentially here you just look for the last bit of the opening tag (namely "**Pswrd>**") then you match any thing between that and the closing portion of the tag.

Comment: Not working as expected: PASSWORD_ONE</abc:Pswrd><Pswrd>PASSWORD_TWO

Comment: Works fine for the input string `String message = "<abc:Pswrd>PASSWORD_ONE</abc:Pswrd>\n" +"<Pswrd>PASSWORD_TWO</Pswrd>";` you specified.

Comment: You can use `[<:]Pswrd>` in your lookbehind which makes sure you match the whole tag name rather than a suffix of it while being fixed-width

Comment: And your solution probably work for you when it doesn't for OP because you matched line-by-line rather than on the whole text. To prevent the mistake, you can either 1) assume there will never be child nodes, and exclude `<` from the result : use `[^<]*` instead of `.*`; or 2) match lazily, using the lookahead to make sure we've reached the first closing tag : use `.*?(?=</(?:[^:>]+:)?Pswrd>)` instead of `(.*)(?=<\/)`

Comment: @Aaron, True, though the solution is not incorrect as the input string specified above has `\n` characters.  Your solution of `(?<=[<:]Pswrd>)[^<]+(?=</(?:[^:>]+:)?Pswrd>)` is better though :)